# Two different keyframes, sharing the same frame/time

Tags: keyframes

any idea about this?
two different keyframes, sharing the same frame/time, if i move any of them left to right if i put it in the same time, different value, the curve its fixed and key frames get fused, one curve two vertex its easy to fix, the problem its that i have an rigify skeleton with this curves bakes from motion capture. 
Some body knows how to clean the curves, clean keyrframes operator ( O ) its not working, too aggressive.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a minimal example blend, and share it with us? Because the screenshot seems to show a very small difference between the timekeys of the two curve points.

Comment: I was trying to copy curves or keyframes, to create an xample file. . . its a bit complicated im not sure why, ill keep trying to generate a sameple file, but it seems that the keys dosnt have the same value. .  but they are too close, keyframe A val -0.0000427  Keyframe B val -0.0000277 practicly invisible unless zoom to much unnoticeable at dopesheet, and as i said clear keyframes it too aggressive and doesn't have in count the distance in time between frames, just the value, the thing is how to clean it

Comment: Select the two keyframes that seem to be the same, then hit [.] on your numpad to zoom in to those two. You should then be able to clearly see the difference, and delete one or the other.

Comment: Sybren, as i said in one curve or two or three its easy to fix, more or less, the deal its the entire skeleton and control bones, are simply too many bones and too many frames to do it one by one.

Comment: If you tell me how you want to select which keyframe to keep, I can write some Python code that automates this for you. The choices are: A) keep the first of the two, B) keep the second of the two, or C) replace both with a point in the middle.